# boolean modifier not working properly

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to create a one-piece bunny suit. ive made the suit i just want to add a seam all around it. I created a mesh to subtract from the suit to make a seam around it.
[image]

[image: before boolean]

then when I apply the boolean modifier to cut it out it destroys it

[image: after boolean]

Comment: please add the boolean modifier to your blend file without applying it ...thx

Comment: Boolean is tricky to use, why don't you simply extrude this seam?

Comment: When your first question is closed for lack of details, you don't need to ask it again in a new question. You can edit the first one by adding details  (like the screenshot you've posted here) to have it re-opened again.

Comment: Yeah I thought about extruding it but I wasn't sure how to extrude it with even thickness all around. do you have any ideas?

Comment: Okay I figured it out. thank you all for you answers they gave me some hope so I messed around with it. all I had to do was click the self intersection box under the Boolean difference solver options drop down.